# Understanding ES6 tagged template literal

Tags: ecmascript-6, template-literals, tagged-templates

Following code snippet is used on Mozilla (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to explain `Tagged Template literal`, please help me understand what following function is doing, i am unable to get the actual flow of the function, since they have used `keys.foreach` and when i inspected in Chrome, keys was a function, so not able to understand

```
function template(strings, ...keys) {
  return (function(...values) {
    var dict = values[values.length - 1] || {};
    var result = [strings[0]];
    keys.forEach(function(key, i) {
      var value = Number.isInteger(key) ? values[key] : dict[key];
      result.push(value, strings[i + 1]);
    });
    return result.join('');
  });
}

var t1Closure = template`${0}${1}${0}!`;
t1Closure('Y', 'A');  // "YAY!"
var t2Closure = template`${0} ${'foo'}!`;
t2Closure('Hello', {foo: 'World'});  // "Hello World!"
```

Comment: "*When i inspected in Chrome, keys was a function*" - no. `keys` is an array.

Comment: yes, key is an array, but somehow when i asked question I inspected keys, when debugger was inside the forEach, that time you cannot access the keys array and if you type keys, you will get a function in console

Comment: Well just write a standard `for (let i=0; i<keys.length; i++) { const key = keys[i]; …` loop instead of the `forEach` call. It doesn't matter for the understanding of template literals.

Comment: I tried with for and forEach and used console.log, in both case we are able to access keys in the loop, but when trying to debug/inspect you cannot get the keys array inside the forEach loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the complexity in the example comes from the overloaded function and the `forEach` invocation, not from the tagged template literals. It might better have been written as two separate cases:

```
function dictionaryTemplate(strings, ...keys) {
  return function(dict) {
    var result = "";
    for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++)
      result += strings[i] + dict[keys[i]];
    result += strings[i];
    return result;
  };
}
const t = dictionaryTemplate`${0} ${'foo'}!`;
t({0: 'Hello', foo: 'World'});  // "Hello World!"
```

```
function argumentsTemplate(strings, ...keys) {
  is (!keys.every(Number.isInteger))
    throw new RangeError("The keys must be integers");
  return function(...values) {
    var result = "";
    for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++)
      result += strings[i] + values[keys[i]];
    result += strings[i];
    return result;
  };
}
const t = argumentsTemplate`${0}${1}${0}!`;
t('Y', 'A');  // "YAY!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Template is a custom function defined by us to parse the template string, whenever a function is used to parse the template string
The first argument of a tag function contains an array of string values. The remaining arguments are related to the expressions. 
 so here specifically we have written the function to that given output
 I had got confused because when in inspected keys inside the forEach, i got a function in console, but inspecting the function before forEach gave keys as the array of  configurable string ${0} and ${1} in first example